# Perl CPAN module object method not found error

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to use a CPAN module: [`Math::Vector::Real::Neighbors`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Vector::Real::Neighbors)

I see the following error message:

> Can't locate object method "box" via package "Math::Vector::Real" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Math/Vector/Real/Neighbors.pm line 12.

So, I go into the package and see this: `my ($bottom, $top) = Math::Vector::Real->box(@_);`

Next, I go into the `Real.pm` package at: `/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Math/Vector/Real.pm`

I see the box sub routine exist in it: `sub box {...`

Any idea why the error might be cropping up?

Comment: What happens before this in your script -- have you created the Math::Vector::Real object?

Comment: add the `use Math::Vector::Real;` just after the `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: @jm666 That answers the question...I was using the example in the synopsys page as-is...my bad...sorry

Comment: @jm666 can you pls post it so I can accept it

Comment: i alarmed alien [already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25769542/176646) that as an answer.

Comment: @sanjay just accept the alarmed alien's answer ;) Thanx anyway ;)

Comment: I was typing it out when jm666 posted the comment... Great minds and all that. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `use Math::Vector::Real` to the top of your script to get Math::Vector::Real::Neighbors to work. The following code runs as expected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::Vector::Real;
use Math::Vector::Real::Neighbors;
use Math::Vector::Real::Random;

my @v = map Math::Vector::Real->random_normal(2), 0..1000;
my @nearest_ixs = Math::Vector::Real::Neighbors->neighbors(@v);
```

But note that it did not work without the line **use Math::Vector::Real**.

Comment: Note: I've submitted a pull request to the author's github repo to add this to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the Math::Vector::Real family of Perl modules.

Nowadays, in order to find the neighbors for a set of points, the algorithm provided in [Math::Vector::Real::kdTree](https://metacpan.org/release/Math-Vector-Real-kdTree) is much better:

```
my @v = ...;
my $kdtree = Math::Vector::Real::kdTree->new(@v);
my @nearest_ixs = $kdtree->find_nearest_vector_all_internal;
```